# External Javascript Doesn't Interact with Button Clicks?

Tags: javascript, facebook

I have a javascript for facebook integration, and it works perfectly when I include it written in the body of my HTML. Now, since I have quite a few pages that all require the facebook auth script, I saved it in a seperate file and include it in all my pages, but when I do this, the script seems to cease to function. Here's the code

```
//Ajax XML Loaders
var xmlhttp;
function loadXMLDoc(url,cfunc)
    {
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {// code for IE6, IE5
xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=cfunc;
    xmlhttp.open("GET",url,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
}
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({appId: 'xxxxxx', status: true, cookie: true, xfbml: true});

    /* All the events registered */
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
        // do something with response
        login();
    });
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
        // do something with response
        logout();
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.session) {
            // logged in and connected user, someone you know
        }
    });
};
(function() {
    var e = document.createElement('script');
    e.type = 'text/javascript';
    e.src = document.location.protocol +
        '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
    e.async = true;
    document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
function login(){
    //Fire the PHP Facebook Auth Script
    loadXMLDoc('http://www.website.com/scripts/php/facebook_auth.php',function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "Success"){
                window.location.reload;
            }else{
                window.location = "http://www.website.com/login_failed.php";    
            }
        }
    });
}
function fblogoutClick(){
    FB.logout(function(response) {

    }); 
}
function logout(){
    //Fire the PHP Logout Script
    loadXMLDoc('http://www.website.com/scripts/php/logout_exec.php',function()
        {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == "Success"){
                window.location.reload;
            }else{
                window.location = "http://www.website.com/logout_failed.php";   
            }
        }
    });
}
```

And I put this in the head:

```
<script src="http://www.thehoppr.com/scripts/javascript/facebook_login.js"></script>
```

The FB login event is fired by a button click, but like I said, if I include this within the body, it works fine, but if I save it externally and load it in the head or body, it ceases to function and I'm not exactly sure why.

Comment: Show us your `<head>` block when you include it as an external script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only reason this would happen would be if the code were not included properly. In terms of the code actually getting run, there's no significant difference between

```
<script>
foo();
</script>
```

and

```
<script src="foo.js"></script>
```

...where foo.js contains `foo();`, provided those tags are in the same place. If you put the inline tag in one place, but you put the external reference tag elsewhere, then of course there's a difference in terms of where the script is.

(There *are* differences, most notably that the browser doesn't have to read through the script code looking for the ending `script` tag, which is a Good Thing; but that probably isn't relevant here.)

The most common errors including scripts are:

- Not including the ending `</script>` tag.
- Trying to use a self-closing tag, e.g. `<script src="foo.js" />` which does not work.
- Getting the path to the JavaScript file wrong. :-)

Comment: I added my header script tag above, when i browse to this link, it brings me right to the script so the path is correct. This is really weird

Comment: @Jacob: Strange! And you're putting that *exactly* where you previously had the inline `script` tag? The only answer is to walk through with a [debugger](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2011/03/no-excuse.html) and figure out what's going wrong. But the script should certainly be getting loaded and run, nothing wrong with that `script` tag. So that suggests some other nuance...

Comment: Well when the script is externalized, I get an error in the console around line 42, which is where it's appending the child to 'fb-root' I had a feeling that the way I was loading the facebook api was probably causing a problem when the script is externalized. I'm just going to put the login and logout functions in the external script and leave the facebook api loaders and that coded into every page's html.

Comment: Apparently when the script is externalized, it's unable to append the loaded api to my <div id='fb-root'> element. So unless you guys know how I can work around it, i'm just going to leave the facebook code in every page, and just exernalize the functions that interact with my php.

Comment: @Jacob: There's no reason why the script being in a separate file rather than inline would have any effect on its being able to add to a `div` on the page. Something *else* is going on.

Comment: Well I give up because this is taking more time to figure out than it ever would have saved me haha. My template now just includes the facebook api loading coded into the html, the functions that interact with my sessions and server php are externalized. Just need to edit the dozen or so pages that already exist

Comment: Of course another workaround could be to send the users who click on the FB login to a separate page, but I much prefer that it all seems seamless so that a user can login from any given page, whether the user is loggin in via facebook or my login

Comment: @Jacob: This answer didn't answer the question, did it? I mean, I think it was helpful, but I don't think it actually solved the problem...

Answer (score 0):

You have most likely not included the script correctly. did you use a self closing tag? (< />)

those are not allowed